# Firebase is not deploying

Tags: angular, firebase, angular7

> This file does not exist and there was no index.html found in the
>   current directory or 404.html in the root directory.

[image]

I have run these codes:

```
> ng build --prod
> firebase login
> firebase init

? Are you ready to proceed? Yes 
? Which Firebase CLI features do you want to setup for this folder? Press Space to select features, then Enter to confi rm your choices. Hosting: Configure and deploy Firebase Hosting sites
```

Then giving the directory:

```
? What do you want to use as your public directory? dist/ishop
? Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? Yes
```

Finally:

```
firebase deploy
```

Comment: no details about angular and firebase version.

Comment: latest version.

Comment: Try init again after deleting firebase.json and .firebaserc files